# apt update gets stuck on cutefish

Tags: 22.04, desktop-environments

I just wanted to install cutefish desktop but it was not successful I closed that terminal and I run `sudo apt update` but it gets stuck on something like cutefish website

How can I solve it ?

Comment: You need to provide the details - output messages etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think that repository is down.
You can open *Software and Updates* and just uncheck that cutefish repository, then you should be able to update and upgrade.

Comment: Thanks , can I also add or remove any other repository by this way ?

Comment: Your welcome Yes you can

Comment: Can you expand on how to "open Software and Updates"? I'm searching in the "launcher" and under the "settings" menu, and I can't see anything like that there.